# CSS: mix-blend-mode working on dark backgrounds, but not on light backgrounds

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the `mix-blend-mode: difference;` property to create a yin/yang color effect on my hero section. My website has a dark mode feature. Interestingly, on dark mode, this works perfectly: the text and navigation bar blends perfectly with the animation, and it looks, to my eye, great. If I switch to light mode, however, the effect goes away and my text is hard to read.

[Here is a GIF](https://infinium-proper.sfo3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/tmp/so-dark.gif) showcasing the (working) effect on dark mode.

[And here it is on light mode](https://infinium-proper.sfo3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/tmp/so-light.gif), not working at all. Notice, however, that the logo in the top-left does appear to work slightly, although the normal circular background is missing.

The dark mode feature is just a class on the `html` element that changes some CSS variables. So, on light mode, `--bg` is `#fff`, and on dark mode it is `#000`.

[I've replicated this issue on a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-banach-5ib4if?file=/src/styles.css), as that is easier for you to play with (but I've pasted the code below, too). Simply comment/uncomment the CSS variables at the top to swap the theme. Note that opening [the sandbox in a new tab](https://5ib4if.csb.app/) makes the scroll animation work.

Here's what I've tried:

- Adding a `background-color` property to the underlying elements
- Adding the `isolation: isolate;` rule to certain elements
- Coloring text with explicit color values (`#000`) or using CSS variables (`var(--text-color)`)

Here's my code (the CodeSandbox link will likely be easier):

**JSX**

```
import useScroll from "./useScroll";

import "./styles.css";

const BoldTextHero = () => {
  const ref = useScroll({
    from: 0,
    to: "bottom-bottom",
    props: {
      "--box-scale-x": {
        from: "0",
        to: "1"
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <section ref={ref} id="bold-text-hero">
      <div className="sticky-wrapper">
        <div className="boxes">
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="wrapper text-c flex-c">
          <h1>Blend</h1>
          <h1>Mode</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default BoldTextHero;
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
  /* DARK — WORKING */
  --ui: black;
  --text-color: white;
  --ui-yinyang: white;

  /* LIGHT — NOT WORKING */
  /* --ui: white;
  --text-color: black;
  --ui-yinyang: black; */
}

html,
body {
  background-color: var(--ui);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#bold-text-hero {
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--ui);
}
#bold-text-hero .sticky-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#bold-text-hero .boxes {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#bold-text-hero .box {
  width: calc(100vw / 9);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--ui-yinyang);
  transform: scaleX(var(--box-scale-x));
  transform-origin: left;
  will-change: transform;
}
#bold-text-hero .wrapper {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#bold-text-hero h1 {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 7rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how the light BG could affect the `mix-blend-mode`. Thank you all in advance—I've been scratching my head at this for some time.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** black color does not make any difference.

Basically, `mix-blend-mode: difference` means that the resulting color would be the *absolute* value of the difference between background color and foreground color.

in case of black text on white: `#fff - #000 = #fff` (becomes white, we don't see it)
in case of black text on black: `#000 - #000 = #000` (no difference, we don't see it)

in case of white text on black: `#000 - #fff = #fff` (remains white as the difference is equal to the initial color, we see it)
in case of white text on white: `#fff - #fff = #000` (becomes black, we see it)

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 50%, #000 50%) repeat-x 0 0 / 25% auto;
  animation: bg 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bg {
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0
  }
```

```html
difference
```